# Can Dragonborn use Breath Weapon more than once per rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, unearthed-arcana, dragonborn

In the Unearthed Arcana "Feats for Races", the Dragonborn feat "Dragon Fear" states (emphasis mine):

> Instead of exhaling destructive energy, you can roar and **expend a use of your breath weapon** to force each creature of your choice within 30 feet of you to make a Wisdom saving throw...

Now, I know this is only Unearthed Arcana and not "official rules", but the wording of this, to me, implies that it's possible for Dragonborn to have multiple uses of their Breath Weapon. However, reading the PHB about Dragonborn, they can only use it once per rest (I can't remember if it's short or long rest, I don't have the PHB in front of me, but it's irrelevant to my question).

So, according to either official rules or other Unearthed Arcana articles, **is there a way for Dragonborn to be able to use their Breath Weapon more than once per rest?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@yinzanat's answer from the question (which I'm about to flag as mine being a dupe of), https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/105497/35259, quoted in full here:

> Yes. There are 5 magic items in Tyranny of Dragons that if the user has a breath weapon that recharges on a rest it has recharge of 6.

A short answer (and I think there are actually 6 magic items, all masks, that grant this recharge ability, but let's not split hairs), but even though it does show a way in which Dragonborn can have more than one use of the breath weapon, isn't the accepted answer to that question. So if you like this answer, go vote  @yinzanat's answer from the other question (I don't wanna take their credit).

This is not to undermine @Szega's answer, which I interpret as a frame challenge regarding my take on the wording, which isn't necessarily the only interpretation of that quote in my question. Hence why I now consider this question an exact dupe of this other question.

Answer (score 5):

The feat you quote does not imply that they can use the breath weapon more than once per rest. It only means that using the frightening effect expends the same resource as using the weapon, ie. you can only use one or the other between two rests.

I know of no ability that would bypass the once per rest limitation of a dragonborn's breath weapon.

Comment: I would argue that the wording "expend **a** use" vs. "expend **the** use" _does_ imply that it's possible to use the breath weapon more than once per rest. Although there's nothing backing that up in the PHB or anywhere else...

Comment: @NathanS Since you get one use every short rest, you have multiplie uses every day, which would account for the phrasing. Using "the" would mean that you have only 1 use *ever*.

Comment: Hmm, I still interpret the way that I interpret it, but you at least have another equally plausible interpretation, enough for me to realise that it's not as clean cut as I originally thought...

Comment: It's just future-proofing. Just because there's no way in the game NOW to get additional uses per rest, doesn't mean there won't ever be.  And a GM can come up with anything they like in their own game.  The feat is just written so that it's clear how it works even if you do have something going on that gives you more than one breath per fight.