# Are you required to spend hit dice to take a short rest?

Tags: dnd-5e, rests, hit-dice

Are you required to spend hit dice to take a short rest?

I couldn't find this anywhere, but my DM is adamant on the idea that in order to benefit from a short rest, you have to spend a hit die. I haven't found anything that supports this. Is he right, or is he maybe just DM house-ruling it?

I mainly was wondering because I play a wizard and it would be helpful to know whether I can use my Arcane Recovery feature during a short rest that others are taking.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

## Hit Dice are not required to be spent during a Short Rest to otherwise benefit from it

> A short rest is a period of downtime, at least 1 hour long, during which a character does nothing more strenuous than eating, drinking, reading, and tending to wounds.
>
> A character **can** spend one or more Hit Dice at the end of a short rest, up to the character's maximum number of Hit Dice, which is equal to the character's level. [...]
>
> —**Short Rest**, Player's Handbook, pg. 186

Emphasis mine. If you were *required* to spend Hit Dice during a Short Rest to take a Short Rest, then the rules would expressly say so, perhaps with language like "*A character **must** spend one or more Hit Dice at the end of a Short Rest **in order to benefit from it***". But they do not.

So if you're a Wizard trying to use your *Arcane Recovery* feature, or a Fighter recovering your *Action Surge*, or a Warlock recovering Spell Slots, or any other character that can gain additional benefits from a Short Rest beyond healing from Hit Dice, you can gain those benefits without spending Hit Dice.

Comment: Thank you. So I guess he was just house ruling it, from our last campaign to prevent a player in the group from just resting every hour with a short rest so that he could get his druid spell slots back to full.

Comment: @necrolance a druid can't recover spell slots on a short rest. How are they doing that?

Comment: @daze413: Land druids have a feature similar to Arcane Recovery... but it, too, is once per long rest.

Comment: @Necrolance Oof, your DM appears to be in the midst of a comedy of errors. ;) Land Circle Druids do have a feature that lets them recover a few Spell Slots on one Short Rest.... ***Only***... one Short Rest, per Long Rest. PHB 68, *Natural Recovery* feature. I respect your DM's intentions to make sure that class features don't overpower the campaign, but I would advise them to pay closer attention to how they work, I think he might find it's not as necessary to revise/houserule things if he better understands their mechanics.

Comment: I appreciate the quick responses. I've already passed the info on, and while he's still concerned I told him that it's ultimately up to the DM on how resting goes. If resting every hour just to make use of 'short rest' features were a major problem he could just limit where we can rest. Or when, like if a place is too unsafe to rest for long. In his defense, he only just recently started being a DM for 5e, and before that he hadn't been a DM for 10 years. And the first group he DM'd was... Less than ideal, which is probably why he instated that. One player did all he could just to push limits.

Comment: @Necrolance There is an answer talking about limiting short rests a bit here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/133653/22403 Your DM may be interested in that one...